# Canvas - Height adjusts itself - Sketch.js

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I am using sketch.js to have a simple sketch board for a mobile app. It is just supposed to fill the full screen through setting width and height to a 100%, but after I click into the "sketch board" it adjusts itself to a smaller size. How do I set the canvas to full screen in this case? This is my example http://jsfiddle.net/66UJ9/

```
<canvas id='mysketch' style="height:100%; width:100%; border: 1px solid black; "></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS's [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) attribute will not refer to the height as the percentage of window, which is what you're expecting. The MDN states:

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to auto

There is no containing block in your Fiddle, and it is not absolutely positioned, therefore it defaults to `auto`. But you can set the `<canvas>`'s height to the browser window with JS like so:

```
// Set the <canvas> height to the window's height
$('canvas').css('height', $(window).height());
```

You may need to adjust this a little depending on how your real page looks. (JSFiddle is adding some padding which throws it off.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. It does work as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/66UJ9/4/ , but the sketching is totally off. Would you recommend doing anything else or using a different js sketch library or is there another fix that you can think of?

Comment: `Sketch.js` seems to be relying on the `height` HTML attribute, not CSS property. Remove the CSS `height` property, and then run this JS: `$('canvas').attr('height', $(window).height().toString() + 'px'); $('#mysketch').sketch();` instead. No problem. If you believe this is the answer to your question, please mark it as the accepted answer so future visitors can find it.

Comment: Indeed, 'future visitors' found it, and found it very useful. +1.